# How to use Tokens with Feeds Module in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, token, drupal-feeds

I'm trying to import data from a custom cell of an excel spreadsheet but can't figure out how to use the mapping tokens.
This would be one of them:

Excel_sheet tokens
[sheet-cell-1-1]    Formatted string of the given cell within the sheet.

So I figure if I input [sheet-cell-1-1] as a source, it should import the first cell from the spreadsheet. But it doesn't. Any suggestions?